# Source RVM script - "grep: invalid option -- 'p'"

Tags: ruby, grep, rvm

Whenever I try to use RVM on Ubuntu or one of it's derivatives, I get the following error:

`grep: invalid option -- 'p'
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.`

I checked `type grep`, and got 
`grep is /bin/grep`.
So grep is not aliased.

Is this a known bug in RVM? If not, what else could be causing this behavior?

EDIT: This occurs when I `source ~/.bash_profile`. I've gone and reproduced the behavior when I run just the RVM related part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `ps='ps ...'` from your config, like .bashrc, or execute `unalias ps` and then run your RVM command.

Comment: Which is what I did. Have a free accept for answering the question.

Answer (score 6):

I had exactly the same symptom intermittently:

```
$ grep anything *
grep: invalid option -- 'p'
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
```

In my case it was actually a file in that directory starting with `-`:

```
$ ls ./'-'*
./-p
```

The solution for me was just to remove the file:

```
$ rm ./"-p"
$ ls ./'-'*
ls: cannot access ./-*: No such file or directory
$ grep anything *
grep: *: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was another command RVM was using that I had aliased.

99 times out of 100, when I'm using `ps`, I'm doing `ps -aux | grep $SOMETHING`. In my .bashrc, I have `alias ps='ps aux | grep'`. In RVM, `ps` is used with the '-p' flag. With this alias, it was registering as `ps aux | grep -p`.

Answer (score 0):

For me I was grepping "-swap" which grep interprets as parameters. Solution is `echo something | grep -- "-swap"`