# "grep: invalid option -- P" error when doing regex in bash script

Tags: bash, macos, grep

I am trying to use a regular expression in a bash script to retreive some text between "(" and ")" and I have this:

```bash
echo "device name, ID: (D96F7842-21D8-4E81-BAE6-DCF8EB66C734)" | grep -P '\((.*?)\)'
```

After executing this in macOS terminal I get:

> ```
> grep: invalid option -- P usage: grep
> [-abcdDEFGHhIiJLlMmnOopqRSsUVvwXxZz] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]  [-e
> pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
>   [--context[=num]] [--directories=action] [--label] [--line-buffered]
>   [--null] [pattern] [file ...]
> ```

I searched for this error and read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23393416/source-rvm-script-grep-invalid-option-p) thread but none of the solutions worked for me. Any ideas?

Comment: `-P` is an option for GNU `grep`. MacOS has BSD `grep`.

Comment: @Jens Did you mean to say `-E`? `-e` has nothing to do with the type of regexp.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59232089/how-to-install-gnu-grep-on-mac-os

Comment: Instead of the non-greedy quantifier, you can use `[^)]*` to prevent crossing multiple `()` groups.

Comment: Better bet on MacOS is with sed: `sed -E 's/^[^(]*\(([^)]*)\).*/\1/'`

Comment: doesn't need external commands: depending on exact format of the string, just:`var='...(...)...'; [[ $var =~ \((.*)\) ]] && echo "found: ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"` may suffice.

Comment: Or Perl: `perl -nE 'say $1 if/\((.*?)\)/'`

Comment: Do a `brew install grep`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your grep command is using a PCRE `.*?` and so trying to use the GNU-only `-P` option to understand it but you're running on MacOS which uses a BSD version of `grep`. Just don't use a PCRE, use a BRE or ERE or similar or some other mechanism that'd let you use a mandatory POSIX tool which will work on every Unix box.

For example, using any awk

```
$ echo "device name, ID: (D96F7842-21D8-4E81-BAE6-DCF8EB66C734)" |
    awk -F'[()]' '{print $2}'
D96F7842-21D8-4E81-BAE6-DCF8EB66C734
```

or any sed:

```
$ echo "device name, ID: (D96F7842-21D8-4E81-BAE6-DCF8EB66C734)" |
    sed 's/.*(\([^)]*\).*/\1/'
D96F7842-21D8-4E81-BAE6-DCF8EB66C734
```

Regarding:

> I searched for this error and read
> [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23393416/source-rvm-script-grep-invalid-option-p)
> thread

Upper/lower case matters in Unix commands, options, arguments, variables, etc. That thread is about lower case `-p` which is unrelated to the upper case `-P` option you were trying to use.

Comment: Not my downvote, but my informal impression is that this must be a common FAQ.

Comment: @tripleee thanks for the feedback. I don't know of any question to close it as a dup of and no-one else has pointed to one and there's several other answers being posted in comments (plus one reference to how to download GNU grep) so idk...